# The server tag is not well formed - running ASP code from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mmenu

I have implemented a mmenu on my ASP.net web app written in C# and Javascript.

The menu is working as expected and I am now trying to add the current users login information to the bottom of the menu, in a fixed footer.

Here is what I have tried.

```
        document.addEventListener(
            "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                new Mmenu("#menu"), {
                    wrappers: ["bootstrap"],
                    "navbars": [
                        {
                            "position": "bottom",
                            "content": [
                                "<div class='jumbotron'>",
                                "<p class= 'lead' > Welcome!</p >",
                                "<asp: LoginName ID=" + LoginName1 + "runat='server' Font-Bold='true' />",
                                "<br />",
                                "<br />",
                                "<asp: LoginStatus ID=" + LoginStatus1 + "runat='server' /></div >"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                };

            }
        );
```

The Javascript validates, however when I try to load the page. I get an error stating "The server tag is not well formed." for this line of code.

```
"<asp: LoginName ID=" + LoginName1 + "runat='server' Font-Bold='true' />",
```

If anyone could help me understand how to resolve this I would be very greatful

Comment: is LoginName  is it your custom control? also there should be space between " and runat='server', also i don't think this is how id is set with variable

Comment: Those asp tags are not valid html and need to be processed server side

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. How do I process server side and then pass to JS as a variable?

Comment: Can you replace those `<asp:` tags with the HTML that they should generate?

Comment: Or for a different approach: always add those controls to the asp page itself (server-side code), but hide the panel that contains them. Use client side javascript to make this panel visible

Answer (score 0):

You simple can not add the **id** like that. This is not how asp.net works

```
"<asp: LoginName ID=" + LoginName1 + "runat='server' Font-Bold='true' />",
```

asp.net controls like `LoginName` must be defined in server and compiled on server. This just not compile.